# Solve the Sturm-Louiville boundary value Problem $u_t(x,t)=u_{xx}(x,t)-bu(x,t)+q(t)$, where $b$ is a constant.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the Sturm-Louiville boundary value Problem $u_t(x,t)=u_{xx}(x,t)-bu(x,t)+q(t)$, where $b$ is a constant. Boundary conditions are $u(x,0)=0$ and $u(0,t)=0=u(\pi,t)$, with $0<x<\pi$ and $t>0$.

Following the only example in the textbook, I get:

Assume $u(x,t)$ is of the form $u(x,t)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B_ne^{-n^2t}\sin(nx)$. But that's for a heat equation: $u_t(x,t)=ku_{xx}(x,t)+q(t)$, boundary conditions $u(x,0)=f(x)$, $u(0,t)=0=u(\pi,t)$.

I don't know what I'm doing and the book and professor are incomprehensible. I really need help.

Comment: I know you are totally changed the question (http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/534608/revisions). Do you make sure you really want to ask $Au_t(x,t)=Bu_{xx}(x,t)+Cu_x(x,t)+Du(x,t)+q(t)$ or $u_t(x,t)=u_{xx}(x,t)-bu(x,t)+q(t)$ ?

Comment: All I really want is to learn how to solve that type of problem. So general, non-homogenous is good.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: let $u(x,t)=e^{a t}v(x,t)$ for an appropriate value of $a$ and obtain an equation for $v$ that you already know how to treat.

**Warning**: the form of the solution you give is for the case $q(t)=0$ and initial data $u(x,0)=f(x)$.

Comment: Could you expand upon this a little more, please?

Comment: I could, but I won't until you show that you have made some effort to follow my hint.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u(x,t)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty C(n,t)\sin nx$ so that it automatically satisfies $u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0$ ,

Then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty C_t(n,t)\sin nx=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^2C(n,t)\sin nx-b\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty C(n,t)\sin nx+q(t)$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(C_t(n,t)+(n^2+b)C(n,t))\sin nx=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty2q(t)\int_0^\pi\sin nx~dx~\sin nx$ , where $0<x<\pi$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(C_t(n,t)+(n^2+b)C(n,t))\sin nx=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty2q(t)\left[-\dfrac{\cos nx}{n}\right]_0^\pi\sin nx$ , where $0<x<\pi$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(C_t(n,t)+(n^2+b)C(n,t))\sin nx=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2(1-(-1)^n)q(t)\sin nx}{n}$ , where $0<x<\pi$

$\therefore C_t(n,t)+(n^2+b)C(n,t)=\dfrac{2(1-(-1)^n)q(t)}{n}$

$(e^{(n^2+b)t}C(n,t))_t=\dfrac{2(1-(-1)^n)q(t)e^{(n^2+b)t}}{n}$

$e^{(n^2+b)t}C(n,t)=\dfrac{2(1-(-1)^n)}{n}\int q(t)e^{(n^2+b)t}~dt$

$e^{(n^2+b)t}C(n,t)=A(n)+\dfrac{2(1-(-1)^n)}{n}\int_0^tq(t)e^{(n^2+b)t}~dt$

$C(n,t)=A(n)e^{-(n^2+b)t}+\dfrac{2(1-(-1)^n)e^{-(n^2+b)t}}{n}\int_0^tq(t)e^{(n^2+b)t}~dt$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(A(n)e^{-(n^2+b)t}+\dfrac{2(1-(-1)^n)e^{-(n^2+b)t}}{n}\int_0^tq(t)e^{(n^2+b)t}~dt\right)\sin nx$

$u(x,0)=0$ :

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A(n)\sin nx=0$

$A(n)=0$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2(1-(-1)^n)e^{-(n^2+b)t}}{n}\int_0^tq(t)e^{(n^2+b)t}~dt~\sin nx=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2e^{-((2n-1)^2+b)t}}{2n-1}\int_0^tq(t)e^{((2n-1)^2+b)t}~dt~\sin((2n-1)x)~,~\text{where}~0<x<\pi$